# Запись аудиопотока из онлайн

Tags: android

На гитхабе нашла проект, где вроде реализована запись аудиопотока из интернета. Но не могу понять где происходит запись в файл на устройстве.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Recorder recorder;
    String streamURL = "http://159.253.37.137:9914/";
    String recordedFileName = "yayin.mp3";
    @BindView(R.id.editTextStreamURL)
    EditText editTextStreamURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        deleteRecordingFile();

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonPlay)
    public void onClickPlay(View view) {

        reCreateRecorder();
        deleteRecordingFile();

        Toast.makeText(this, recorder.getUrlPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        recorder.record();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonPause)
    public void onClickPause(View view) {
        recorder.stopRecording();
        reCreateRecorder();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonPlayFromRecord)
    public void onClickPlayFromRecord(View view) {
        recorder.playFromRecording();

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonStopFromRecord)
    public void onClickStopFromRecord(View view) {
        recorder.stopPlayingFromRecord();
    }

    public void deleteRecordingFile() {
        File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "yayin.mp3");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    public void reCreateRecorder() {
        if (recorder != null) {
            if (recorder.isRecording()) recorder.stopRecording();
            recorder.player = null;
            recorder = null;
        }
        if (!editTextStreamURL.getText().toString().equals("")){
            streamURL = editTextStreamURL.getText().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            streamURL = "http://159.253.37.137:9914/";
        }
        recorder = new Recorder(this, streamURL, recordedFileName);
    }

}
```

Recorder

```
public class Recorder extends AsyncTask {

    private Context context;
    private String urlPath;
    private String recordedFileName;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    Player player;

    public Recorder() {
    }

    public Recorder(Context context, String url, String recordedFilePath) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urlPath = url;
        this.recordedFileName = recordedFilePath;
        this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        player = new Player(context,recordedFileName,urlPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        isRecording = true;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

            File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), recordedFileName);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024];
            int read;

            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                if(isCancelled())
                    break;
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    public void record()
    {
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(),recordedFileName);
        if (file.exists())
        {
            file.delete();
        }

        player.play();

        this.execute();

    }

    public void stopRecording()
    {
        isRecording=false;
        this.cancel(true);

        player.stop();
    }

    public void playFromRecording()
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), recordedFileName);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getPath());
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopPlayingFromRecord()
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getUrlPath() {
        return urlPath;
    }

    public void setUrlPath(String urlPath) {
        this.urlPath = urlPath;
    }

    public String getRecordedFileName() {
        return recordedFileName;
    }

    public void setRecordedFileName(String recordedFileName) {
        this.recordedFileName = recordedFileName;
    }

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isRecording;
    }

    public void setRecording(boolean recording) {
        this.isRecording = recording;
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    }

}
```

Player

```
public class Player  {

    // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
    Handler mainHandler;
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    TrackSelection.Factory audioTrackSelectionFactory;
    DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;

    // 2. Create the player
    SimpleExoPlayer player;

    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter;
    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    MediaSource audioSource;

    Context context;
    String recordedFileName;
    String urlPath;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Player(Context context, String recordedFileName, String urlPath) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recordedFileName = recordedFileName;
        this.urlPath = urlPath;


        // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
        mainHandler = new Handler();
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        audioTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(audioTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);


        // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(urlPath));

    }


    public void play() {
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(audioSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    public void stop() {

        player.stop();
        player.release();

    }    

}
```

Как вообще реализовать запись в файл?

Comment: Вроде бы в этой строке: `outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);`

Comment: А как я могу его сохранить в файл на устройстве?

Comment: По идее, вам надо в строке `File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), recordedFileName);` заменить `context.getCacheDir()` на нужный вам путь в общедоступном месте. Например на такой: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` - должно в папку с документами сохранить. Проверьте, что при этом нужные разрешения приложению выданы.

Comment: Да, сохраняет, но только не могу понять следующее: Нажала Play и через секунду нажала Pause, по идее записанное аудио должно длиться 1-2 секунды, а записалось 17 секунд.

Comment: В коде записываются байты, не секунды. Засим так и выходит - сколько байтов принялось за пару секунд - столько и записалось. Чтобы сделать как вы хотите - надо смотреть есть ли возможность как-то декодировать приходящие данные на лету... Не факт, что можно. Точно можно постфактум отрезать лишнее. Если нужное кол-во секунд запишется в файл за время работы кода. На медленном соединении может и не успеть.

Comment: Понятно, можно пояснение почему тут byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024]; именно 4*1024? Почему например не 2*1024?

Comment: Этого я не знаю( Могу лишь предположить, что это может влиять на кол-во оперативной памяти. Наверное, если число будет очень большое, то можно упасть по нехватке памяти.

Comment: понятно, спасибо за помощь!